# Are there other ways to time travel in the Potterverse?

Tags: harry-potter

There are a lot of questions about the time turners in Harry Potter.  There's a fan theory that Ron could have used one and become Dumbledore at some point in the past (but that's been debunked).  I also asked [Why Couldn't a Time Turner Have Been Used to Stop Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/11946/1693).  It seems that Rowling had them all destroyed to stop time travel issues (such as paradoxes or the idea that one could be used to just undo all the bad with Voldemort before it started).

The time turners are magic machines, so they had to be created at some point.  But are they the only way to time travel and why couldn't one use the same type of magic a time turner uses to move back in time more than just an hour?

Comment: @JasonBaker: I had kind of mixed feelings about including that, but thought it better to have a broader than a narrow span.

Comment: Dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54360/how-are-time-turners-made

Comment: Oops. Meant to flag for community approval.

Comment: Okay, @Richard: Since there's the "How were they made" question, I've changed it to ask if it's the only method and why one can't move back more than an hour at a time.

Comment: You can, it's just ill-advised. Dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/why-couldnt-a-time-turner-have-been-used-to-stop-voldemort?s=11|1.7148

Comment: I felt that my answer on this one was pretty definitive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum: Sorry.  When I see answers posted soon after the question, I like to allow a few more days before selecting one, to give more people time.  I must have lost track and forgot to get back to this question to pick an answer.  Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Pottermore](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Time-Turner), the time-turners are a charm housed in an attractive container;

> According to Professor Saul Croaker, who has spent his entire career
>   in the Department of Mysteries studying time-magic:
>
> We have been able to encase single Hour-Reversal Charms, which are
>   unstable and benefit from containment, in small, enchanted
>   hour-glasses that may be worn around a witch or wizard’s neck and
>   revolved according to the number of hours the user wishes to relive.

So the answer is; yes, a spell (or rather a charm) can be used to travel without the time-turner but not as conveniently.